# iOS-Webservice: Webservice for iOS client

Tags: ios, eclipse, web-services, tomcat7

I am developing an iOS app, which will have to send some info such as Student name, address, roll number, semester type to a web service. The web service will receive these info and need to respond simply "received successfully" to the iOS client.
I am not very familiar with creating such web services support, though i know java very well.

I have done program on iOS part already, except need to direct a url web service.
I am having Eclipse and Tomcat 7.0 server added in Eclipse. I need to create web service project now and have ability to receive such students details from an iOS client and respond in the localhost environment for testing.
My question is, Could someone share me tutorials/help for creating such web service project in Eclipse + Tomcat environment and for my project purpose?

Please note, i am asking just for testing purpose, not release public. I am running my mac machine as server machine, where eclipse and tomcat already bundled.
I am asking to study tutorial like this-> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn8vLBOEhic

Thank you!

-Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the flow: Eclipse->Dynamic Web project->add your web service code->create as wsdl service. Use this wsdl service file in your client project and access the web service APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a small project and fairly simple on the backend (as is described) I'd suggest looking at a backend-as-a-service solution, such as [Parse](https://parse.com/) or [Firebase](http://www.firebase.com)

Comment: You can also use http://backbeam.io

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to web services. For my app I used this code which I think it can be adopted in your case:

```
-(IBAction)addData:(id)sender{

[self displayActivityIndicator];

NSString *studentName = self.studentNameTextField.text;
NSString *studentAddress = self.studentAddressTextField.text;
NSString *rollNumber = self.rollNumberTextField.text;
NSString *semesterType = self.semesterTypeTextField.text;

NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&address=%@&&rollNumber=%@&semester=%@", studentName,
                    studentAddress,
                    rollNumber,
                    semesterType];

NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/savedata.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

NSString *success = @"success";
[success dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)responseString.length);
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)success.length);



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // Dismiss the viewController upon success

}
```

savedata.php

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');


$db_conn = new  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase','admin','password');
$db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$message = "";
$name = ($_POST['name']); 
$address = ($_POST['address']);
$rollNumber = ($_POST['rollNumber']);
$semester = ($_POST['semester']);


$qry = $db_conn->prepare('INSERT INTO  myTable(`name`,`address`,`rollNumber`,`semester`) VALUES (:name,:address,:rollNumber,:semester)');
$qry->bindParam(':name', $name);
$qry->bindParam(':address', $address);
$qry->bindParam(':rollNumber', $rollNumber);
$qry->bindParam(':semester', $semester);

$qry->execute();

if ($qry) { $message = "success"; }
else { $message = "failed"; }

echo utf8_encode($message);
?>
```

Comment: I am not asking this. I am asking to development step by step tutorial for web service project in eclipse + tomcat environment. What you are showing is the iOS code. I am asking tutorial like this-> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zn8vLBOEhic

Comment: .. sorry I can't help with that;-)